# Leer datos transformados de una respuesta XML a JSON en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, xml, soap

Tengo una duda. Estoy haciendo una petición http a un webservice, con normalidad me retorna un response de tipo XML. Luego estoy transformando divha respuesta a Json para poder interpretar y usarla a mi conveniencia con las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```js
axios
        .post(`${baseURL}`, xmls, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
                SOAPAction: '',
            },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const result = convert.xml2json(response.data, {compact: true, spaces: 4})
            const jsonResult = JSON.parse(result)
            res.status(200).json({
                ok: true, 
                soap: jsonResult
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    ok: true,
                    soap: 'error obtener el soap',
                });
            }
        });
```

de esa forma con normalidad me transforma a formato Json pero llego a un punto en donde quiero traer un valor de ese Json.

```html
{
  "ok": true,
  "soap": {
    "_declaration": {
      "_attributes": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "encoding": "UTF-8"
      }
    },
    "soapenv:Envelope": {
      "_attributes": {
        "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Quiero traer los datos que estan dentro de la clave **soapenv:Envelope** pero al ejectuar normalmente en cualquier objeto Json **jsonResult.soapenv:Envelope** me envia un error porque en la parte intermedia hay dos puntos **:** entre **soapenv** y **Envelope**. Si alguien me podria ayudar o guiarme. le agradeceria de antemano...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En estos casos puedes usar la notación estilo array: `jsonResult["soapenv:Envelope"]`

Te dejo un ejemplo del enlace de más abajo aquí para demostrarlo:

```js
const person1 = {};
person1['firstname'] = 'Mario';
person1['lastname'] = 'Rossi';

console.log(person1.firstname);
// expected output: "Mario"

const person2 = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
};

console.log(person2['lastname']);
// expected output: "Doe"
```

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) puedes leer acerca de cómo acceder a las propiedades de ambas maneras.

Comment: Gracias si pude solucionarlo